I encounter the following error when trying to import the iOS build in Flutter
command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/burakkaynar/Desktop/socify/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist /Users/burakkaynar/Desktop/socify/ios/Runner/Info.plist ->

node: /Users/burakkaynar/Desktop/socify/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:Copy /Users/burakkaynar/Desktop/socify/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex /Users/burakkaynar/Desktop/socify/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex ->

node: <target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase5--cp--embed-pods-frameworks> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase5--cp--embed-pods-frameworks ->

node: /Users/burakkaynar/Desktop/socify/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/OneSignalCore.framework

After following the OneSignal instructions and doing everything, I encounter the above error when I want to build.
I just tried
pod install


can you provide the oneSignal version and share the configuration that you followed ?

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk-setup
onesignal_flutter 5.1.5

In Xcode, in your app target build phases, you should have something called "Embed App Extensions" or "Embed Foundation Extensions" at the end of the build phases. If you drag it BEFORE "Run Script", it should prevent this build error to happen.
Check this screenshot to see where "Embed Foundation Extensions" phase in the list is placed

you can find more info here

Worked for me, thanks a lot
